# Laravel/Php - Modify the collection in eager loading closure?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, eager-loading

I'm trying to modify this query:

[image: Eager loading query]

The function of the helper class returns me the products left by removing the amounts used in sales, etc. It works fine if I use dd() inside the function. However, the $products collection isn't changed, what am I missing to successfully modify the base $products array with the collection returned by the helper?

If it helps, here is the helper class:

[image: Helper class]

If there is a better way to handle this, I am glad for every suggestion.

Best regards

Edit:

I've tried the answer in the comment to pass the helper as closure parameter but still no luck.

[image: Closure implementation]

Comment: You have tô pass the helper as closure parameter...

Comment: I've tried what you suggested, not sure you meant it this way. I still have no luck with this problem. @SamuelAialaFerreira

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add a `return` inside the with orders function

```
return Helper::calculateNumberOfQuantityLeftPerOrder($query->get());
```

Comment: I've tried, the result is the same. Thank you for the suggestion though.